# Switch between two columns based on a condition in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_reports_reviewers]
    @compid    INT,
    @jobid     INT,
    @startdate DATETIME,
    @enddate   DATETIME,
    @columns   VARCHAR(8000) OUT
AS
    SET @columns = 'Job ID, Job Title, Admin, Job Start Date, Job End Date, Job Status, Job Type, Reviewer First Name, Reviewer Middle Initial, Reviewer Last Name, Reviewer Email, Default PPid, Custom PPid, Reviewer Role, Reviewer Added'
    
    SELECT
        jobusercompany.job_id,
        jobusercompany.job_title,
        jobusercompany.f_name + ' ' + jobusercompany.l_name AS Admin,
        CAST(jobusercompany.auction_start_date AS DATE) AS StartDate,
        CAST(jobusercompany.auction_end_date AS DATE) AS EndDate,
        CASE
            WHEN jobusercompany.auction_start_date > GETDATE() 
                THEN 'Future'
            WHEN jobusercompany.auction_start_date < GETDATE() 
                 AND jobusercompany.auction_end_date > GETDATE() 
                THEN 'Open'
            WHEN jobusercompany.auction_end_date < GETDATE() 
                THEN 'Closed'
            ELSE ''
        END AS Status,
        job.job_type,
        ahuser.f_name as 'Reviewer First Name',
        ahuser.mi as 'Reviewer Middle Initial',
        ahuser.l_name as 'Reviewer Last Name',
        ahuser.email,
        ahuser.pp_id,
        userjobprev.pp_id,
        permissionsprofile.pp_name,
        CONVERT(varchar, userjobprev.last_update_ts, 101) AS 'Reviewer Added'
    FROM 
        jobusercompany
    INNER JOIN 
        userjobprev ON userjobprev.job_id = jobusercompany.job_id
    INNER JOIN  
        ahuser ON ahuser.user_id = userjobprev.user_id
    INNER JOIN 
        permissionsprofile ON permissionsprofile.pp_id = ahuser.pp_id
    INNER JOIN 
        job ON job.job_id = jobusercompany.job_id
    WHERE 
        jobusercompany.auction_start_date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate 
        AND jobusercompany.state = 1 
        AND jobusercompany.company_id = @compid 
        AND jobusercompany.jobuser_id <> userjobprev.user_id
    ORDER BY 
        jobusercompany.auction_start_date DESC, job_id
```

I get this result set: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YMb9.png (*Please refer the image for the result set*)

**Goal**: for a given row, if a value in custom ppid is zero, it should get value from default ppid.

I am not able to achieve the end result, I really appreciate, If someone helps me to get the desired result set.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And you need to provide sample data that would produce your required results. Also if you create a [mre] with the emphasis on minimal you're probably solve it and then be able to add the rest of the query back.

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: Do you want to add a new column for this condition or you want it to be in Custom PPID?

Answer (score 0):

This is easily solved with a simple case expression. I have no idea where you want this in your query but see if the below makes this work for you.

```
select
...
case when CustomPPid = 0 then DefaultPPid else CustomPPid end
...
```